# Hibernate criteria query taking time to fetch records from data base table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, criteria, hibernate-criteria

In my project I am inserting 10000 records into table. If any record is already available we are fetching it by using hibernate criteria and comparing it with new record. We have very less data in table around 10000 records. For the hibernate criteria we have applied conditions. This hibernate criteria is fetching 6 records from table. But why it is taking time if I call criteria.list() method for fetching 6 records

HIbernate criteria query:

```
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ where (this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') and this_.DEL_DTIME is null and ((this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='en' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='GB' and this_.ID='A1000') or (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='en' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='GB' and this_.ID='AP1000') or (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='pt' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='PT' and this_.ID='AP1000') or (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='pt' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='PT' and this_.ID='A1000') or (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='s1' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='SI' and this_.ID='AP1000') or (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='s1' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='SI' and this_.ID='A1000'));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's hibernate that takes time? Did you try to invoke this SQL query (which is not a hibernate criteria query) directly on the database console? If this does not take time, I'd like to know the name of the company or product of the DBMS used. Because they have invented an innovative, disruptive piece of technology.

Comment: If i execute same query in database console it is not taking time I am getting the result immediately

Comment: Could you describe a little better how are you inserting the records and verifying existing records? Are you inserting each record through persist/save? Do you have batch configured in your sessions factory? Do you verify your table after every insert?

Comment: First we are fetching the record the from table if the record is already available or not.If available any update for that record we are updating. else we are inserting the new record in the table. Yes we are verifying after insert into table. We are updating and inserting using merge() method

Answer (score 1):

Considering the information from the question and comments, this is what is going on your code:

- For every record to be inserted, you do a select, through a criteria.
- Do a check and depending on the situation, you either persist or merge a record.

You have to understand how hibernate sessions behave in some situations. When you perform an operation in hibernate, what you're doing (in the first moment) is updating the hibernate session. Either in an insert, delete or update, the operation will be performed in the session, Hibernate will even log a SQL statement, but **it won't be flushed immediately** to your DB (yes, it is misleading).

Usually everything is flushed and the end of a transaction, but in certain situations hibernate will flush operations to keep the session up to date. In your case, you have multiple records to be inserted/merged, but before each operation you perform a select. Hibernate detects this operation and will flush every previously stored operation, simply because it makes no sense to query the DB if there are pending operations to be flushed. The DB needs to be in the most up to date state that is possible. Don't try to fight this, it's designed to work this way.

So my best guess is that when your select takes too much time to be executed, it's because **hibernate is flushing the previous insert/update operation**.

How to solve it:

I can't think of any straightforward way to solve this. You'll have to reconsider your approach.

There is one thing that is important: even if you only had to pure inserts without any verification, you would have some trouble because your code is trying to insert thousands of records. The big problem with this is that, like I wrote earlier, hibernate won't flush the operations until the end of transaction. So, it will keep in memory every statement to be performed. There is a good chance that you'll run out memory.

The first thing I would do is to check hibernate docs on batching (start with it's [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch)). After that, I would figure out a strategy to optimize the need inserting a large number of records and the verification needed.
Instead of working with single records, work with chunks of data.

From the little information available, I would try this workflow:

Before everything, define the batch size property for hibernate (again, check the docs on batching)

- When processing your data, take a slice of your data with the same size defined for batch size
- Do a select that selects every possible record to be verified within those records that are to be inserted
- Perform the needed verifications to check if it's a merge or insert for every record in the slice
- Group inserts and merges and perform the operations. Flush and clear hibernate session
- Take the next slice of data, and repeat the process

Basically it's the "same" procedure you're doing, but it will be done for chunks of records instead of doing it in every single record.

Comment: Hi Vitor, before creating criteria I am deleting the entities which are already available in session then the performance got improved                                                       Map entities = ((SessionImplementor) getSession()).getPersistenceContext().getEntityEntries();
    if (entities != null)
      entities.clear();

Comment: It looks like you are clearing the session, but in a way that I have never seen before (usually I see session.clear() or entityManager.clear() ). 
It is important to flush the session/entityManager before clearing it otherwise you'll risk losing consistency.
I am inclined to say that this is not correct. If you plan to go with this, do a serious round of testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the query in this way:

```
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='en' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='GB' and this_.ID='A1000') 
UNION ALL
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='en' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='GB' and this_.ID='AP1000') 
UNION ALL
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='pt' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='PT' and this_.ID='AP1000') 
UNION ALL
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='pt' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='PT' and this_.ID='A1000') 
UNION  ALL
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='s1' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='SI' and this_.ID='AP1000') 
UNION ALL
select this_.CLASS_TYPE as CLASS1_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE as CLASS2_15_0_, this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE as CLASS3_15_0_, 
this_.ID as ID15_0_, this_.LANG_CODE_ISO as LANG5_15_0_, this_.CTY_CODE_ISO as CTY6_15_0_, this_.NAME as NAME15_0_, this_.INS_DTIME as INS8_15_0_,this_.UPD_DTIME as UPD9_15_0_, this_.DEL_DTIME as DEL10_15_0_ 
from FI_SALES_LOCATION_V this_ 
where 
(this_.CLASS_TYPE='BU' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_TYPE='STO' and this_.CLASS_UNIT_CODE='A1000') 
and this_.DEL_DTIME is null 
and (this_.LANG_CODE_ISO='s1' and this_.CTY_CODE_ISO='SI' and this_.ID='A1000');
```

Even if it is more to write, the performance is improved when you perform UNION ALL rather then OR.

Or you could index the table, but you will loose performance on INSERT.

Comment: hi the above query is generated by hibernate at run time

Comment: Then, the best way is to create an index on table with the following columns: LANG_CODE_ISO, CTY_CODE_ISO, ID. The performance will be improved on the OR conditions.